# Character class VS. Character list

Tags: python, class, variables, pygame

On nearly all of the example programs for pygame, characters are instantiated as classes with some code like this one:

```
class Character(object):
    def__init__(self,image,stuff):
        self.image = image
        self.stuff = stuff[:]

bob = Character(image,stuff)
```

I am wondering what the benefit of using a class is over using just a plain list. I could instead of using class instantiation just create a list like this:

```
bob = [image,stuff[:]]
```

I was wondering if the reason that people use classes is to have functions that interact directly with the character and are just defined as a part of the class rather than as a separate function that can be used on the character.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a class `Bob` over a list `bob` in this simple case:

- Easy access to an attribute. It's simpler to remember `Bob.image` than `bob[0]`. The longer the list is, the harder it gets.
- Code readability. I have no idea what the line `bob[7]=bob[3]+bob[6]` does. With a class, the same line becomes`Bob.armor=Bob.shield+Bob.helmet`, and I know what it does.
- Organization. If some functions are only meant to be use on characters, it's practical to have them declared just after the attributes. A class forces you to have everything related to characters at the same place.

Instead of a list though, you could use a dictionary:

```
bob = {"image":image, "stuff":stuff[:], ...}
bob["armor"]=bob["shield"]+bob["helmet"]
```

As with a class, you have an easy access to attributes and code is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd say it's more clear.  With the `list`, you'll end up wondering "what was at index 0?  what was at index 1?" and so forth.  Then you'd have to trace back through the code to find where `bob` was defined to make sure.

Additionally, if you create other characters throughout the code, you have to create them all the same way.  With the `class`, you can easily search the codebase for character creations and update it (e.g. if you want to add another property to characters) and if you miss any, python will throw an `Exception` so you know where to fix it.  With the list, it's going to be really hard to find and python won't tell you if you miss any -- You'll get a funky `IndexError` that you need to trace back to the root cause which is more work.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `class` you might be able to inherit from other `class` and create `method`s, which doesn't apply to `list`s. But if you know that you will only be using static values like your `class Character` does, you might check out `namedtuple`. Here's a simple example how to use it:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Character = namedtuple('Character', 'image stuff')
bob = Character(image, stuff)
```